# Checking for membership in an Erlang guard

Tags: erlang, if-statement, guard

What is the simplest way to write an if statement in Erlang, where a part of the guard is `member(E, L)`, i.e., testing if `E` is a member of the list `L`? The naive approach is:

```
if 
  ... andalso member(E,L) -> ...
end
```

But is does not work becuase, if I understand correctly, `member` is not a guard expression.  Which way will work?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Member functionality is, as you say, not a valid guard. Instead you might consider using a case pattern? It's possibly to include your other if-clauses in the case expression.

```
case {member(E,L),Expr} of
  {true,true} -> do(), is_member;
  {true,false} -> is_member;
  {false,_} -> no_member
end
```

Comment: Nice.  I hoped to avoid using booleans as case clauses, but at least it spares me the need to nest a case statement inside an if statement.

Comment: Using booleans in case statements is quite common, probably more common than any use of "if".

Answer (score 6):

It is not possible to test list membership in a guard in Erlang. You have to do this:

```
f(E, L) ->
    case lists:member(E, L) of
        true  -> ...;
        false -> ...
    end.
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest thing is to consider guards as a part of pattern matching, the part which cannot, or is difficult to, express in the pattern itself. So a guard is a sequence of *guard tests* and not boolean expressions. The original guard syntax made it easier to see the difference but now they look like boolean expressions, which they are not.