# Can I make my own Guards in Erlang?

Tags: erlang, guard

I came accross this code on the web:

```
is_char(Ch) ->         
    if Ch < 0 -> false;  
       Ch > 255 -> false;
       true -> true      
    end.

is_string(Str) ->            
    case is_list(Str) of           
    false -> false;           
    true -> lists:all(is_char, Str)
    end.
```

Its is the Guard I alwais dreamed off, in that it checks if an input is a string -- how ever, I'm not allowed to use it in erlang, why is this? And is there a work around?

I would like to be able to write stuff like:

```
Fun(Str) when is_string(Str) -> Str;
Fun(Int) when is_integer(Int) -> io:format("~w", [Int]).
```

or even better use it on messages.

Comment: No offense but, a better way of testing for strings would be the methods: `io_lib:printable_list/1`  and `io_lib:printable_unicode_list/1` used in combination.

Comment: See also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10861347/why-comparing-function-results-is-an-illegal-guard-exception-in-erlang), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6505213/is-there-a-way-to-use-local-function-in-guard), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6927632/checking-for-membership-in-an-erlang-guard), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241340/unable-to-use-function-call-in-function-guard) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7474894/use-of-function-in-guard-not-allowed-suggestions-for-alternate-implementation-w) question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are not allowed to use user defined functions in the guards. It is because the functions in the guards have to be free from side effects (such as using `io:format` in your functions). In guards, you are limited to the following:

- BIFs used for type tests (`is_atom`, `is_constant`, `is_float`, `is_integer`, `is_list`, `is_number`, `is_pid`, `is_port`, `is_reference`, `is_tuple`, `is_binary`, `is_function`, `is_record`),
- boolean operators (`not`, `and`, `or`, `andalso`, `orelse`, `,`, `;`),
- relational operators (`>`, `>=`, `<`, `=<`, `=:=`, `==`, `=/=`, `/=`),
- arithmetic operators (`+`, `-`, `*`, `div`, `rem`),
- bitwise operators (`band`, `bor`, `bxor`, `bnot`, `bsl`, `bsr`),
- other BIFs that are free of side effects (`abs/1`, `element/2`, `hd/1`, `length/1`, `node/1,2`, `round/1`, `size/1`, `tl/1`, `trunc/1`, `self/0`)

Comment: Hmm, it would seem that checking for side effects would be a pretty easy static-analycis trick...

Comment: @MartinKristiansen Not really, because any code in modules can be changed or replaced at runtime.

Comment: @alexeyRomanov: You are absolutely correct -- but perhaps then make a restriction to use BIF's and only functions inside the current module :-)

Comment: @MartinKristiansen That would have to be "Only BIFs and those functions inside the current module which call only BIFs and functions inside the current module and aren't recursive (to ensure they terminate)". Which means that you can't use `is_string` as a guard, after all :)

Comment: @MartinKristiansen ...or functions that use special constructs such as `receive` that always perform a side effect.

Comment: But if NIFs and C-Nodes are allowed (which can also crash the entire runtime) why aren't custom guards?

Answer (score 6):

Another reason for not allowing user defined functions in guards is that errors are handled differently in guards than in "normal" functions. In a guard an error does **not** generate an exception, it only causes the guard itself to fail.

Guards are not really expressions but *tests*.